Merge “file-encryption” tag with “encryption”?
I just noticed we have a file-encryption tag and an encryption tag:

encryption (1,603 questions tagged)
Encryption is the process of transforming plaintext using a cipher into ciphertext to make it unreadable to anyone except those possessing the key. Decryption is the process of transforming that ciphertext back into plaintext, using the key. 
file-encryption (86 questions tagged)
The process of encrypting individual files on a storage medium and permitting access to the encrypted data only after proper authentication is provided.

As “file encryption” might as well be regarded to be a sub-category of “encryption”, the question arises if we should merge both (making “file-encryption” a synonym of “encryption”).
So, what do you think? Does it make sense to merge the “file-encryption” tag with “encryption”, or should we keep both as seperate tags?

Why not make a vote of it ? Upvote if yes, Downvote if no. No ?

@Biv When it comes to suggested tag edits like this, people tend to share their opinion too… which is why I didn’t limit this to a simple Yes/No voting Q&A. Even when things will boil down to a Yes/No thing in the end, an open question like this leaves some room to potentially explain why they are “pro” or “contra” if they want. (Wouldn’t be the first time someone comes up with a perfect reason for a “No”, which only becomes apparent due to the accompanying explanation/reasoning.)

I think it is useful to have (a) tag(s) for "encrypting data at rest", in contrast to encryption in a real-time protocol.
Whether file-encryption is the right one, I'm less certain, but I don't think it should be merged into encryption.

I disagree that there's a useful distinction to be made there. The biggest difference -- if there is one to be made -- is symmetric vs asymmetric encryption.
